# Ordenação de paginate em CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Nunca ouvi falar de CakePHP, estou com um pouco de dificuldades para ajustar um script comprado onde o desenvolvedor não oferece suporte.

Esse código é responsável por listar alguns registros de imagens salvas no banco de dados.

```
        public function choose(Request $request)
        {
            $memes = $this->meme->paginate(10000);

            if ($request->has('ajax')) {
                return $this->jsonPagination($memes, view('ext-meme::partials.memes', compact('memes')));
            }

            return view('ext-meme::choose', compact('memes'));
        }
```

Elas são listadas em ordem crescente de acordo com o que foram inseridas no banco.

Como ficaria o código para listar em ordem reversa? Os últimos registros sendo exibidos primeiro.

Comment: Qual o código da função $this->meme->paginate? 
É cakephp2 ou 3?

Answer (score 0):

**Para ordenação decrecendo utilize o 'DESC' e para listar de cima para baixo utilize o 'ASC'.**

```
    public function choose(Request $request)
    {
        $memes = $this->meme->paginate(10000)->order(['nomeColuna' => 'ASC']);;

        if ($request->has('ajax')) {
            return $this->jsonPagination($memes, view('ext-meme::partials.memes', compact('memes')));
        }

        return view('ext-meme::choose', compact('memes'));
    }
```